# How to make a function inline in C++

Tags: c++, inline-functions

To make a function inline should I add the keyword inline in function prototype or in function definition or should I add the inline keyword both in function declaration and function definition.

Comment: Note that the `inline` keyword is only a *hint*. The compiler is free to disregard it. And it's also free to compile functions *not* marked with `inline` as inline.

Comment: As for your problem, if all the compiler have is a declaration of a function, it often can't inline it no matter if you used the `inline` keyword or not. A definition (implementation) of the function is needed to be able to inline it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude does it make sense to use `inline` keyword to inline functions with a modern compiler? or should we let the compiler decide for us most of the time?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to add the keyword for definitions you feel are good candidates for inlining. Also note that member functions that are defined inside the class-definition are automatically `inline`, even if you don't add the keyword.

Comment: @Ayxan you don't have too much choice here.

Comment: @n.m. can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @Ayxan The `inline` keyword does **not** mean "inline calls to this function". You can do basically nothing about the fact

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a declaration and definition, you don't need to add `inline` anywhere. The inline keyword is not a magical optimization incantation, but more of a linkage specifier.

An inline function must be defined in every translation unit it's used in. How can it be defined there? Simple, it's put in header:

```
// foo.h
inline void foo() {}
```

But wait, I hear you say, won't putting it in header cause a multiple definitions error? Not when it's marked inline, that's why I called it more of a linkage specifier. The inline specifier tells the compiler that all those multiple definition it sees are the same. So it may in fact use any one of them. Or it may inspect the function body and choose to do code inlining, but it doesn't have to.

The primary purpose of the keyword is to allow those multiple definitions to appear inline, not to cause the function's code to be inlined. So again, if you have a definition in a cpp file and a declaration in a header, you don't need to do anything. If you have a utility you want to appear in a header, put it there - definition and all - and add the inline keyword.

Answer (score 3):

> How to make function inline:
>
> To make any function as inline, start its definitions with the keyword “inline”.

From the [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/).

Comment: can I omit the keyword inline in function declaration

Comment: No, but as @Some programmer dude mentioned, just mentioning the keyword inline doesn't make it inline as it depends on the function code if it includes iterations,recursion etc